# Twitter API Standard Search: Can I get hidden replies?

Tags: api, twitter

I am trying to get as much data as a I can out of the Twitter API for an academic research project. Even though I only have access to the Standard API the data should be as accurate as possible. I am building myself a "wrapper" around Twarc and other utilities in Python that gets me most of the data I want in just the format I need. A big problem was getting all the replies, but I was able to solve it with a bit of trickery: Searching from the tweet in question onwards and then checking if the tweets in the obtained sample have the original tweet ID in "in_reply_to_tweet_id". Rinse and repeat with those newly obtained tweets.

Then I noticed the new moderation feature Twitter implemented in March. Now the moderated comments under "More replies" do not show up in my search output.

Example: https://twitter.com/NDRreporter/status/1113353224730365952

I find all replies except the following: Under "More replies" ("Mehr Antworten" in German), there is a reply chain started by a extreme right leaning (possibly troll) account ("@Der Steuerzahler") that got moderated and shoved down there. This does not show up in API searches, even if I let the code iterate for over an hour just looking for replies to this particular original tweet.

My question is pretty general: Aside from getting replies as they come in (i.e. before they are moderated) via Filter API, is it possible to find these moderated tweets via the Standard Search API? Not looking for a ready-made solution, general pointers suffice. If I can't find them via Search, then I obviously won't try it with that anymore.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You’re asking for data that is not served via the Twitter API. This is simply not available via any route.

Comment: I found a solution myself via using the API. If you parse tweets published since the tweet you're interested in and then get all the mentions, you can actually find replies that were moderated away. You simply find handles in a conversation that are likely to be moderated away (mentioned but no replies by these handles found). Then you go through the timelines of these handles and look at the 'in_reply_to...' fields. THis can be done solely by relying on the API and some logical thinking. The solution gets all replies but is likely not scalable. I will provide a real answer when I have time.